# HTML stuff on suggested edit review page

Tags: bug, status-completed

I looked at the review page of my suggested edit and I found this:

[image: Weird HTML stuff]

Why does it look like a span element in html with title of a time and it's displaying next to the "proposed"?

**Update:** This is not just showing on the suggested edit page, it's also showing up as blank HTML on the edit revisions page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now and everything is back to its place.